# Confused regarding #if expressions

Tags: c

I am learning C using Visual Studio 2015. If I create a brand new project and execute nothing other than the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
#if abc == xyz
    printf("Expression is true.");
#else
    printf("Expression is false.");
#endif
}
```

the application prints out the string `Expression is true` which is something I was not expecting. The reason I was not expecting this to work like this is because I was expecting a compile error given that the `abc` and `xyz` tokens are not defined or declared anywhere in code. **So the question is why is this working?**

Finally, if I declare and define `abc` and `xyz` as follows:

```
int abc = 123;
int xyz = 456;
```

the application prints out the string `Expression is true`? This looks clearly wrong doesn't it? **Why is it that if I declare and define the variables as integers with different values I trigger the #if and not the #else?**

Thank you.

Comment: `#define` doesn't use `=` for its syntax. It's `#define IDENTIFIER string`, then the C pre-processor will replace `IDENTIFIER` in the code with `string` before the C compiler even gets to it. Arguments to `IDENTIFIER` can also be provided. Just google search "C #define syntax" and find, for example, [this information](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/teas0593.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: That's not how the `#define` directive is used, if you define it like that then `abc` will be replaced by `= 'a';` literally. Also, if `abc` and `xyz` are not defined I would expect `#if abc == xyz` to be true.

Comment: The C Preprocessor does not interact with normal C code, at all. They have completely different syntaxes, and you cannot use C variables in the preprocessor like you are trying to.

Comment: @lurker: I edited the post (fixed the #define = 'a' ..... ) to reflect what I really meant to ask. I was rushing while posting this and I totally screwed it up. I will checkout your link. Thanks.

Comment: @iharob: That was a mistake. See my response to lurker. Thanks.

Comment: Semicolons are not part of the syntax either, unless you want the semicolons to be part of your substituted string. You should read the documentation. I think that will clear up some of your issues.

Comment: @lurker: True, man, I really suck at this. I am trying to learn C in a day and its not working out very well. I removed the whole paragraph because it was wrong. Thanks.

Comment: You've got 3 different questions here. It's best to try and keep things to 1 question per post, especially since you keep getting the syntax wrong and changing the question. Your first question is a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5085392/1287251) (which, despite being about C++, was answered with a C answer (and later edited to include the C++ answer, which is the same)). The answer to your second question is the same as the first (the preprocessor does not care about your declarations that exist outside of the preprocessor).

Comment: If you can't learn C in a day, that doesn't mean you suck at it. A single day is a very aggressive goal. You need time to study and try things out. Study has to be part of it, or your just guessing.

Comment: @Cornstalks: Lesson learned.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion would be, at least in the first few days (weeks/months/years?) of using C, don't use the preprocessor `#` commands, other than,

1. to `#include` library headers, and
2. to `#define` flags if required by those headers.

Trying to do anything else with the preprocessor is not worth the effort and confusion.

In this case, use a regular if statement:

```
if ( abc == xyz ) {
    printf("Expression is true.");
} 
else {
    printf("Expression is false.");
}
```