# Why doesn't #error directive give the expected result here?

Tags: c, embedded, microcontroller

I am writing a "gpio" device driver for my AVR ATmega32 microcontroller. The driver has an initialization function that's shown below. I use enums to pass configuration to the function. An example of calling this function is

```
gpio_init_port(MY_PORT_A, INPUT, HIGH);
```

This would set PORTA as input with default value HIGH. I use switch statements to check the passed configuration to set the corresponding port as input or output. Now I thought of using #error preprocessor directive in the "default" case of the switch statement in case a user enters a wrong input, for example

```
gpio_init_port(5, INPUT, HIGH);
```

so compilation stops and an error message is printed. But I do not know why it's not working as I expect. The part of the code I am referring to is this:

```
default:
#if (port_number != MY_PORT_A && port_number != MY_PORT_B && port_number != MY_PORT_B && port_number!=MY_PORT_D)
#error "Wrong Input. You have entered invalid port number."
#endif
```

The expression

```
(port_number != MY_PORT_A && port_number != MY_PORT_B && port_number != MY_PORT_B && port_number!=MY_PORT_D)
```

doesn't evaluate and the error message isn't printed. But when I change it to

```
#if (1)
#error "Wrong Input. You have entered invalid port number."
#endif
```

It works fine.
Another issue that I have is that when I write something like

```
gpio_init_port(5, ***OUTPUT***, HIGH);
```

The error message is also printed although I am passing "OUTPUT" this time and this not supposed to happen since the default case is defined only for the "INPUT" case.

```
gpio.h
______

typedef enum port_number{
   MY_PORT_A=0,
   MY_PORT_B,
   MY_PORT_C,
   MY_PORT_D
} port_number_t;
typedef enum port_direction{
   INPUT=0,    
   OUTPUT
} port_direction_t;
typedef enum output_state{
   LOW=0,
   HIGH
}output_state_t;
void gpio_init_port(port_number_t port_number, port_direction_t port_direction, output_state_t initial_value);
```

---

```
gpio.c
________
#include "gpio.h"
void gpio_init_port(port_number_t port_number, port_direction_t port_direction, output_state_t initial_value)  
{
switch (port_direction)
{
case INPUT:
{
    switch (port_number)
    {
    case MY_PORT_A:
    DDRA=0x00;
    PORTA=initial_value? 0xff:0x00;
    break;
    case MY_PORT_B:
    DDRB=0x00;
    PORTB=initial_value? 0xff:0x00;
    break;
    case MY_PORT_C:
    DDRC=0x00;
    PORTC=initial_value? 0xff:0x00;
    break;
    case MY_PORT_D:
    DDRD=0x00;
    PORTD=initial_value? 0xff:0x00;
    break;
    default:
    #if (port_number != MY_PORT_A && port_number != MY_PORT_B && port_number != MY_PORT_B && port_number!=MY_PORT_D)
    #error "Wrong Input. You have entered invalid port number."
    #endif
    break;
    }
}
case OUTPUT:
{
    switch (port_number)
    {
    case MY_PORT_A:
    DDRA=0xff;
    PORTA=initial_value? 0xff:0x00;
    break;
    case MY_PORT_B:
    DDRB=0xff;
    PORTB=initial_value? 0xff:0x00;
    break;
    case MY_PORT_C:
    DDRC=0xff;
    PORTC=initial_value? 0xff:0x00;
    break;
    case MY_PORT_D:
    DDRD=0xff;
    PORTD=initial_value? 0xff:0x00;
    break;  
    }
}
}
}
```

So, what is exactly wrong here?

I have read that enums can't be used in conditional compilation, but I don't know if that's truly right and the reason of the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please avoid asking multiple questions at once.

Comment: @klutt, man, where are those multiple questions?!!

Comment: Maybe I was a bit quick. The reason was that you wrote "Another issue that I have", but I'll retract the close vote.

Answer (score 6):

these statements

```
#if (port_number != MY_PORT_A && port_number != MY_PORT_B && port_number != MY_PORT_B && port_number!=MY_PORT_D)
#error "Wrong Input. You have entered invalid port number."
#endif
```

are evaluated at preprocessing/compile time. So they're evaluated whatever the outcome of the `switch` statement. In that case you're trying to test `port_number` which is a variable in the `#if` macro, which isn't possible.

In general, the `#error` directive is useful for instance when some preprocessor constants are conflicting, *at compilation time*, certainly not *at run time*. The example you're quoting

```
#if (1)
#error "Wrong Input. You have entered invalid port number."
#endif
```

"works" (well it's not very useful as is) because `1` is a compile-time constant.

You want to test that at runtime, and throw a kind of "exception" when running:

```
default:
{
   fprintf(stderr,"at %s line %d: Wrong Input. You have entered invalid port number.\n",__FILE__,__LINE__);
   exit(1);
}
```

no need for the `if` since all 4 cases have been ruled out by the `switch` statement.

Also note that you can insert the handy `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` compilation-time values so you know where in the source code the error was raised (unless you want to use `assert(0);` directly)

Answer (score 3):

The preprocessor  `#if` can only test for values that have been `#define`'ed earlier. It knows nothing about variables, parameters, or enum values.

And everything that doesn't come from a `#define` [is given a default macro value of 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5085392/what-is-the-value-of-an-undefined-constant-used-in-if).

So your test turns out as

```
#if (0 != 0 && 0 != 0 && 0 != 0 && 0 !=0)
```

And this will of course never trigger the `#error` message.