# NVCC fails with the error ""_GLIBCXX_MATH_H" is not defined"

Tags: cuda, nvcc, compiler-options

I'm compiling a CUDA program - a simple and innocuous one. Regardless of how far I simplify it or remove some of the code or the include files, nvcc tells me:

```
In file included from /usr/local/cuda/bin/..//include/crt/common_functions.h:271:0,
                 from /usr/local/cuda/bin/..//include/common_functions.h:50,
                 from /usr/local/cuda/bin/..//include/cuda_runtime.h:115,
                 from <command-line>:0:
/usr/local/cuda/bin/..//include/crt/math_functions.h:8891:5: error: "_GLIBCXX_MATH_H" is not defined [-Werror=undef]
```

I'm using CUDA 9.0 or 9.1 on Linux, and CUDA is using GCC (either 5 or 6). Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: This ought to have a [mcve]

Comment: And what compiler are you using?

Comment: @talonmies: See my answer :-)

Comment: @RobertCrovella: Not really, because I want to make it clear that the answer is relevant to many such cases and not to a very specific example.

Comment: @einpoklum: The problem with that is that I have CUDA 9 and CUDA 9.1 and every supported gcc and clang version installed on the platform I use and I have *never* gotten that warning. Ever.

Comment: @talonmies: Try building ModernGPU and you'll get it (see the [Makefile](https://github.com/moderngpu/moderngpu/blob/master/Makefile)).

Comment: @einpoklum: But below you said that an empty main will trigger this error. Which is it?

Comment: @talonmies: Both - it's about the compiler flags, not the source. ModernGPU has this problematic choice of compiler flags.

Comment: So *what* compiler flags, exactly?

Comment: @talonmies: Explained in my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### tl;dr: Change your problematic compilation flags.

In CUDA 9.0 and 9.1, nVIDIA is a bit sloppy about using certain macros before checking they've been defined. That is, indeed, a sort-of-an issue with the header files `crt/math_functions.h`, `crt/math_functions.hpp` and `math_functions.hpp` (in the CUDA include directory).

However, this is usually not an actual problem, since [an undefined macro defaults to a value of 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5085392/what-is-the-value-of-an-undefined-constant-used-in-if) (in C and probably in C++ too). And indeed, by default, neither gcc nor nvcc will complain.

In your case, however, something is making GCC run with `-Wundef`, which warns you about these cases, and `-Werror`, which escalates all warnings into errors. Since what you're invoking is `nvcc`, the command-line (which you, likely, did not write yourself) probably has `-Xcompiler="-Wundef"` and `-Xcompiler="-Werror"` somewhere.

Removing the latter of these two will make `nvcc` succeed (barring other errors), and removing both will make the warnings go away as well.

Comment: Are you importing headers from `crt`?

Comment: @talonmies: Nope. Actually, the code could be simply `int main() { }` and that's it.