# How to get rid of the need to define a preprocessor macro for conditional compilation?

Tags: c++

I have some C++ code compiling depending on some `#define`. Today I mistakenly forgot to `#include` the file with the defined, which lead to my program being compiled with the wrong code.

What are my options to get rid of this potential error?

Comment: Refactor your code not to need it? It's a little hard to answer such a broad question in another way.

Comment: It really depends on what they are doing.  Without seeing the code there isn't much concrete advice we can give you.

Comment: "One issue i got today is i forgot to add the file" you cannot forget to add a file when you work with C++, you can easily get UB.

Comment: OP, your question was unclear but I think I got it anyway. I've edited it. If you think it is no better, you can rollback your question to what it was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have the macro header either `#define FOO` or `#define NFOO`.

You would then test for exactly one of `FOO` or `NFOO` to be defined

```
#if defined(FOO) && defined(NFOO)
#error both FOO and NFOO defined
#elif defined (FOO) 
    // foo case
#elif defined (NFOO) 
    // not foo case
#else
#error neither FOO nor NFOO defined
#end
```

Comment: I like this solution better as it does not pollute with define the compiler command.

But on this base I though it could became much better using values; a non-define var is 0, so then 1 may be "defined" and 2 "undefined" and avoid the issue of double declarations:

#lif defined (FOO == 1) 
    // foo case
#elif defined (FOO == 2) 
    // not foo case
#else
#error  FOO not defined
#end

Comment: @mauro if `FOO` is not defined, it is neither `0`, `1`, or `2`. You'd have to `#if defined(FOO) #if FOO == 1 ... #elif FOO == 2 ... #else #error unknown FOO #end #else #error missing FOO #end`, which is also rather verbose

Comment: the standard explicitly say "remaining identifier" are set to 0, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5085392/what-is-the-value-of-an-undefined-constant-used-in-if

Answer (score 5):

Most compilers let you define preprocessor macros within the compilation command line. For instance, g++ and clang++ have `-DMACRO=VALUE`.

`trunit.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    #ifdef ALT_FOO
        std::cout << "BAR\n";
    #else
        std::cout << "FOO\n";
    #endif // ALT_FOO
}
```

In the current situation you're in, this code's behaviour would depend on the inclusion of a header file defining or not the macro `ALT_FOO`. You can control that from the build process itself:

```
$ # build the FOO variant:
$ g++ -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic -O2 trunit.cpp -o foo
$ ./foo
FOO

$ # build the BARvariant:
$ g++ -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic -O2 -DALT_FOO trunit.cpp -o foo
$ ./foo
BAR
```