Preprocessor #if equality directive not working as expected
Could someone here please help me understand why I am seeing the following error rather than the GATEWAY error? Thank you.
root@GATEWAY-0x0000001E:~/gateway/experiments# cat compile_define.cpp
#define DEVICE_TYPE GATEWAY

#if DEVICE_TYPE == NODE
    #error "NODE"
#elif DEVICE_TYPE == GATEWAY
    #error "GATEWAY"
#endif
root@GATEWAY-0x0000001E:~/gateway/experiments# g++ compile_define.cpp -o compile_define.o
compile_define.cpp:4:6: error: #error "NODE"
    4 |     #error "NODE"
      |      ^~~~~
root@GATEWAY-0x0000001E:~/gateway/experiments# g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 13.2.0-4ubuntu3) 13.2.0
Copyright (C) 2023 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

root@GATEWAY-0x0000001E:~/gateway/experiments#


Neither GATEWAY nor NODE are defined. DEVICE_TYPE gets none. None is equal to none.

Related:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5085392/what-is-the-value-of-an-undefined-constant-used-in-if     Although this linked Q&A is for C, my understanding is that the required effect in C++ is the same  (but unsure offhand if that's via reference to the C standard, or relevant clauses in the C++ standard).

Fixed with:
#define DEVICE_TYPE_GATEWAY 0
#define DEVICE_TYPE_NODE    1

#define DEVICE_TYPE DEVICE_TYPE_GATEWAY

#if DEVICE_TYPE == DEVICE_TYPE_NODE
    #error "NODE"
#elif DEVICE_TYPE == DEVICE_TYPE_GATEWAY
    #error "GATEWAY"
#endif

Thanks to 273k for the answer.
