# Can I include preprocessor directive inside my function

Tags: c++

I have read that I am not able to include preprocessor directives inside my function. But when I implement it, it works. Here are my code:

```
#include <iostream>

#define MY_CONSTANT 41

void myFunction(int x) {

    #if x == 42
       std::cout << "Value is 42." << " "<<x<<std::endl;
    #else
       std::cout << "Value is not 42." <<" "<<x<< std::endl;
    #endif
                       }

int main() {
  myFunction(42);
  return 0;
           }
```

'The output was not like what I expected. It is: Value is not 42, 42. Could you explain me what really happened here. Why the directive come to the else statement.'

Comment: The preprocessor runs *before* the actual code is parsed. As such it have no idea about variables in the actual code, only defined macros.

Comment: You could as write `#if adhfsgfhsfglkjn` and get the same result. For preprocessor your `x` is simply not defined, so a whole condition evaluates to false. This could help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1643874/4165552

Comment: The preprocessor does not know about `x`, so `x == 42` is false. As such, by the time the code gets to the compiler, the function looks like `void myFunction(int x) { std::cout << "Value is not 42." <<" "<<x<< std::endl; }`